# How to ask user to enable Bluetooth on NativeScript without use Native Code

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, nativescript

I need to ask the user to enable Bluetooth, but I do not want to use native methods of each platform, is there a standardized way in NativeScript for this?

Which classes should be used for this type of request so that the code will be compatible with both iOS and Android platforms, or whatever they may come up with?

I need a code like this for iOS and Android:

```
  DemoAppModel.prototype.doEnableBluetooth = function () {
    bluetooth.enable().then(function(enabled) {
   if(!enabled)
      setTimeout(function() {
    /* I need this code for iOS and Android */
    Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
      }, 500);
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the nativescript-bluetooth plugin and use [the method shown in the demo app](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-bluetooth-demo/blob/c2ab60663125deddc1ce1f5dba1db04dd78af785/Bluetooth/app/main-view-model.js#L14-L20):

```
bluetooth.isBluetoothEnabled().then(function(enabled) {
  // show an alert dialog or some nicer UI, if 'enabled' if false
});
```

Btw, on Android you can even programmatically enable Bluetooth on the device (it will ask the user's consent) by using [this method of the plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-bluetooth-demo/blob/c2ab60663125deddc1ce1f5dba1db04dd78af785/Bluetooth/app/main-view-model.js#L24-L32):

```
bluetooth.enable().then(function(enabled) { /* .. */ });
```

Comment: Hi @Eddy-Verbruggen, firs all thanks for the plugin, very good, but not work with Bluetooth Classic. 
I update the Question.